# What is the proper way of using JavaScript, jQuery and AJAX to avoid reaching CPU limits?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-3

Maybe I think this script below is causing me High server load make my site down as well as CPU reach limit. Is there a proper way to code the variables and arrangement of this script?

One point here also, I am using here a `SetTimeout()` because I *really need* to get data from a JSON file from Codeigniter PHP and MySQL every 2 seconds. Is there any other way to set this in proper way? What can I do  minimize my server load and avoid reaching the limit of the CPU of my web host?

```
<script>

var data1;
var data2;
var id = "1";
var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/get_products/';

products();

function products() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get(url + id, function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data)
        data1 = obj.product[0].data1;
        data2 = obj.product[0].data2;
        if (obj.product[0].data2 == "") {
            document.getElementById("datap").innerHTML = "No data found";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("datap").innerHTML = data1 + data2;
        }
    });
});
setTimeout(products, 2000);
};
```

server side: (mycontroller.php)

```
public function get_product($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query =  $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            $data['product'] = $query->result();
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Put the code back, your question is useless without it.

Comment: Not sure its a "pure code" problem but maybe more a strategic one. If you want to get data from your server, you can call it directly like with a "link" which will cause it to send back to you the entire data. You can also use the XMLHttpRequest object to get back from server only the data you need (and the JS on client side will display.  (see http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp). Rather than asking JSON to encode, you can also send back only the data (shorter and faster). The CPU limit is strange and maybe depend on the PHP code quality and request number?

Comment: A detail: on PHP side, I think you have "PHP code" and also "SQL Query". Add some microtime() info around each call to see what need time. Knowing where time is lost is first point in order to know where the effort must be done.

Comment: i update the code

Comment: Show the PHP code so the server side.

Comment: that is my code on the server side. my client side is an android app sending data to server.

Comment: i think setTimeout is the problem? i consumes lot of memory. what can i do about it?

Comment: @Peter i updated the code for server side

Comment: ??? You say you use PHP and MySQL but there is no PHP nor MySQL in this code. Also, to send data to Android, you just have to "echo" the value. Are you're trying to send data to a Webview?

Comment: sorry for lack of info.. i use codeigniter to echo a json_encode..

Comment: update description.

Comment: OK. I think the problem is not the PHP code. I think you're confuse between the php code execution time and the data transfert.  put  $star_time= microtime(true);  at start of the PHP code and  $end_time = microtime(true);
 $ecart = $end_time - $star_time;
 $ecart = round($ecart,4); 
after and you'll the time of the query. I think you'll be FAR from 2 sec.

Comment: what that code do? i just put it on the php file where my function is

Comment: For info, I update a lot of data for my Android App from Web server. Querying about 10 tables with complicated query need about 0.01 sec. But the data transfert to the tablet need more than 5 sec.

Comment: This code get the microtime() the system and then do the same after and substract the two. So you get the number of milisecond needed for the code.

Comment: ok. is setTimeout()? set a heavy traffic to my database?

Comment: also my data transfer is from Android device to Web, so i set setTimeout to 2000 milliseconds so i can retrieve new data every 2 seconds on my database sent by Android app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122775/discussion-between-peter-and-cross).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122776/discussion-between-peter-and-cross).

Comment: One AJAX request per user every two seconds is certainly going to add up, if you have a non-trivial number of users. However this in itself is not too heavy - it is the MySQL query that will put the load on the system. How long does the query itself usually take to run?

Comment: You may need to move to a host that does not add CPU limits in this fashion. If you are on a shared host, maybe in the short term you could do with moving to a VPS. However, if you are using AJAX for data polling, maybe Web Sockets would be a better idea - for which you'd need a VPS or third-party service anyway. Web Sockets are much lighter than repeated HTTP requests.

Comment: also, i am sending data, queriying (Update product where product_id etc etc........) from Android to my Website and Database Every 2 seconds. is it another cause for reaching the cpu limit?

Comment: Im' sure we're not searching the right way. If data are send from Android to the server, in many cases, it would be completly impossible to send data every 2 sec not due to the code but due to internet speed. As Android work in Async mode, if first call need 3 sec to transmit, I think the second call will occur before the end of the first and create problem over problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with Cross I think we've find the problem. He's creating and Android map which looks for GPS coord, and send them to a PHP script on a web server. The PHP script update the record of the vehicle with the lat and Long, using the id of the vehicle (it's a car tracker) to know which record must be  updated.
Then an other PHP script reads the database and, using JS, move a marker on a map.
The problem came from the fact Cross was using a timer in the Android App to ask GPS position every 2 sec, but he was calling the web server inside a loop without "timer". So in pseudo code he had something like that:

```
  Every 2 sec, ask for GPS Location
  Do
      send Location to server
  Loop
```

So even if the GPS location was uptaded only every 2 sec, he was calling the web server at full speed in continous.... which explain the CPU overload.
I suggest Cross to such a think

```
       Get GPS location every 2 sec
       Do
          if Location has changed
            send to server
          endif
       Loop
```

Comment: Your solution Get GPS location every 2 sec Do if location has changed send to server endif Loop. is working the location will ONLY send if location has change if not Stop send. Yes it is working BUT last night after testing for 30 mins i got Error message on my Webhost "Database stop responding TOO MANY REQUEST TRAFFIC to your mysql database". after 20mins "CPU Reach Limit you website will be back within 24 hours".

Comment: Is it problem on my webhost or on my code? is it too much server load?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the query code. Send a mail and we'll solve that rather that using Stack for talking. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no use of `$(document).ready(function () {...}` inside the `locate` function

Also you have place the `setTimeout` outside the `function locate`

```
function locate() {
  $.get(get_loc + v_id, function(data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data)
    longtitude = obj.vehicle[0].longtitude;
    latitude = obj.vehicle[0].latitude;
    if (obj.vehicle[0].longtitude == "") {
      document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "No coordinates found in the database";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "Longtitude: " + longtitude + "<br>Latitude: " + latitude + " ";
    }
  });
};
setTimeout(locate, 2000);
```